# Can $R[x,1/x]$ be isomorphic to $R'[t]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

There already exists quite similar question on MSE.

> [Show that $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is not isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415542/show-that-kx-y-xy-1-is-not-isomorphic-to-a-polynomial-ring-in-one-variable/4544806#4544806)

Now it is interesting to ask such question for any commutative ring with identity. So:

*Let $R, R'$ be commutative rings with identity. Is it possible that $R[x,1/x]\simeq R'[t]$?*

It is clear that the argument used for proving the original stament cannot be adapted for our problem.

Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: yes, this is certainly possible. for example let $R=A[t]$ and $R'=A[x,x^{-1}]$ for any commutative ring $A$. moreover it is even possible to have $R[t]\cong R[x,x^{-1}]$; indeed let $R=A[t_i,x_i,x_i^{-1}:i\in\mathbb{N}]$ for any commutative ring $A$

Comment: Yes, take $R=R'=0$.