# How to prove that these two quotients are isomorphic as rings (circle and hyperbola)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider the polynomial ring $A=k[x,y]$. Consider the ideal $I=\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle$ (which is just the vanishing set of the circle) and $J=\langle y^2-x^2-1\rangle$ (the vanishing set of the hyperbola). How to prove that $$A/I\cong A/J.$$

Consider $K=\langle y-x^2\rangle$. How to prove that 
$$A/K\ncong A/I.$$

Comment: If $k=\mathbb C$, then you can do a linear change of coordinates sending $x^2+y^2$ to $y^2-x^2$. I think maybe $u=x+iy$ and $v=x-iy$ works.

Comment: I asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984063/circle-and-hyperbola-over-mathbfp2-bbb-r some time ago :-)

Comment: I have another idea (but its  validity depends on proving that $I=\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle$ is prime in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$). Correct me if I am wrong. If $I$ is prime, then $R/I$ is integral domain. Then the ideal $L=\langle I+x, I+y\rangle$ is not principal in $R/I$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/ring-of-trigonometric-functions-with-real-coefficients says that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle$ is a PID. Then we cannot use our previous idea (that $A/I$ is not a UFD and $A/K$ is) to prove that $A/I\ncong A/K$.

Comment: In $A/I$, $\langle x,y\rangle  = \langle 1\rangle $.

Comment: The first comment solves the first question (which is pretty simple), and the second question is settled here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463572/show-that-bbb-cx-y-i-is-not-isomorphic-to-bbb-cz?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, over an algebraically closed field, the line, circle, hyperbola, and parabola are all isomorphic *projective* varieties.

Up to isomorphism, the only difference between these rings, then, is which *points at infinity* they are missing. Your circle and hyperbola are each missing two points ($(1 : \pm i : 0)$ and $(1 : \pm 1 : 0)$ respectively), and the parabola is missing one point: $(0:1:0)$.

With one point removed, the coordinate ring of each of these curves is isomorphic to $k[t]$. Removing a second point corresponds to inverting the appropriate linear function. By a suitable change of variable, we can insist that the result is isomorphic to $k[t, t^{-1}]$.

For the parabola, the correspondence is $(x,y) = (t, t^2)$. For the hyperbola, one such correspondence comes from $t = x+y$ (and $t^{-1} = y-x$). For the circle, $t = x+iy$ (and $t^{-1} = x-iy$) works.

So, the remainder of the problem is to show that $k[t]$ and $k[t, t^{-1}]$ are not isomorphic as rings. There are probably lots of ways to do this (including some geometric argument using the count of missing points I described above); however, a  simple method is to compute the unit group.

Comment: In the similar posts I've seen so far it's asked to prove that $k[t,t^{-1}]\not\simeq k[z]$ (I wouldn't write $k[t]$) as rings, not as $k$-algebras. Moreover, all the proofs assume (by contradiction) the isomorphism is of unitary rings. It would be interesting to find out a proof without this assumption (which means to find other properties of the two rings not involving units).

Comment: To prove my point see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050291/show-that-quotient-rings-are-not-isomorphic?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @user26857: A ring that is also a $k$-algebra (i.e. a ring with a specified homomorphism to it from $k$, or a ring extension of $k$ or other equivalent formulation) is certainly what's intended by the question, but I did intend to edit my first draft to switch over to just plain rings, and apparently missed an occurrence; I've corrected.

Comment: I can understand this, but the question has been posted for few times and all the OPs have looked for a non-isomorphism as rings. Most likely the question is an exercise in a textbook (I think could be Vakil notes), and I suppose this was the requirement there.