# Group ring $R(G)$ isomorphic to polynomial ring $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $G$ an infinite multiplicative cyclic group with generator $g$. Is the group ring $R(G) \cong R[x]$?

My guess is that for $R = \mathbb{Q}$ this is not true. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Try $R[x,\frac1x]\cong R[x,y]/(xy-1)$ instead.

Comment: What is wrong with $f : R(G) \to R[x]$ given by 

$$f(r_0 +r_1g + r_2g^2 + \cdots +r_ng^n) = r_0 + r_1x +r_2x^2 + \cdots + r_nx^n$$

Comment: @Arthur $R[x,\frac{1}{x}]\cong R[\mathbb Z]$ by mapping integers to integer powers of $x$, right? Seems the same as what the OP is describing.

Comment: @FlybyNight: $g \in R(G)$ is a unit, but your map then takes $g$ to $x \in R[x]$, which is not a unit. (More pertinently, the infinite cyclic group generated by $g$ also contains $g^{-1}, g^{-2}, \ldots$, so your definition is incomplete.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim Yes, of course, an infinite cyclic group doesn't "wrap around", so the negative powers need considering. I guess a Laurent series is the place to start, would that make $x$ a unit?

Comment: @FlybyNight: yeah, that's the right idea: then the map you wrote down (extended appropriately to negative powers) is exactly what one wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, yes. $\mathbb F[\mathbb Z]$ is isomorphic to the Laurent polynomials $\mathbb F[x;x^{-1}]$, and this is [never isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1050315/29335) to $\mathbb F[x]$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the help