# Show that two quotient rings are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I looked at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050291/show-that-quotient-rings-are-not-isomorphic) but am not able to apply the answers there to my problem.

The problem is this:

> Given an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero, consider the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$. Let $I = (y^2 − x^3 − x^2)$ and let $J = (xy)$ and define $A = k[x, y]/I$ and $B = k[x, y]/J$. Show that $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic.

I don't even know where to begin, perhaps I can use some sort of parameterisation as in the other thread? If anyone can hint at how I can get started I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe $I$ is an integral domain as it contains no divisors of zero and $J$ is not an integral domain as the product of two nonzero polynomials say $p(x,y)=x$ and $q(x,y)=y$ is a zero polynomial $xy$ in $J$.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over a field of characteristic $0$ the polynomial $y^2-x^3-x^2$ is irreducible, thus making the ideal $I$ a prime ideal and the quotient ring $A$ a domain.

On the other hand the ideal $J$ is not prime (just from the definition of prime ideal: $x$ and $y$ are not element of $J$ but their product $xy$ is) and so the quotient ring $B$ is not a domain.

Hence $A$ and $B$ cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you! How can one see that that polynomial is irreducible? Eisensteins criterion?

Comment: @Wallgrenovic : Some attempts factorizing $y^2-x^3-x^2=P(x,y)Q(x,y)$ will soon convince you of the impossibility (note that $P$ and $Q$ need to be linear in $y$ and at most quadratic in $x$). Else, observe that the plane curve $y^2=x^3+x^2$ is irreducible: it is a plane cubic with a nodal singularity in the origin.

Comment: Thanks again! Factorizing led me to contradicitons like you suggested.

Comment: Why need the characteristic zero in order to conclude that $y^2-x^3-x^2$ is irreducible? This holds over every field (and over every integral domain).