# $\mathbb{K}^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is not group isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field with infinite cardinality and $\mathbb{K}^\times$ its group of units under multiplication (i.e. all elements except $0$). I want to determine if $\mathbb{K}^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is group isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}^{\times}$ or not. Intuitively I'm inclined to say not, since the first "has a lot more elements" than the second, but I'm not sure because weird things can happen with infinite groups, like proper subgroups being isomorphic to the whole group and so on.

Just to be clear, the operation equipped on $\mathbb{K}^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is $(k,m) \star (h,n) = (k\cdot h, m+n)$.

This question was inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050291/show-that-quotient-rings-are-not-isomorphic?noredirect=1&lq=1). In the second answer, this same question is solved for $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$, using the fact that $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is a divisible group. But that's not true for $\mathbb{R}^\times$ for example, so I cannot use it in the general case. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well, the obvious homomorphism (The one that just forgets the second component) fails to be injective, badly.   I'm not seeing why $\mathbb{R}^\times$ fails to be divisible?  Every nonzero real number can be written as $n$ times another real number

Comment: @Alan I'm talking about the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{R}$, so $n$ times would mean $y^n = x$ which is not always solvable (e.g. for even $n$ and negative $x$). About the homomorphism, I'm aware that one is not injective, but how can I prove that there exists no isomorphism at all?

Comment: The same argument holds for any radically closed field (fields for which the polynomials $x^n-a$ always have a root for all $a$)

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{R}^{\times}\cong \mathbb{R}^{\times}_{\gt 0}\times C_2$; this is nothing but the decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ into its divisible and reduced parts. The positive reals are divisible under multiplication, and the $C_2$ component keeps track of the sign. This is clearly not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}\times\mathbb{Z}$, since moding out by the torsion subgroup in $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ yields a divisible group, but in the latter a group that is not divisible.

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you're looking for--it's true for some choices of $\mathbb{K}$, and false for others.  I wouldn't expect any nice classification of the $\mathbb{K}$ for which it is true.

Comment: Or are you trying to claim that it is always true, so a single counterexample would be a satisfactory answer?

Comment: @EricWofsey Do you have any example where $\mathbb K^\times \times \mathbb Z \cong \mathbb K^\times$?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $C_2\times(\oplus\mathbb{Z})$. This is isomorphic to $C_2\times\mathbb{Z}\times(\oplus\mathbb{Z})$ (the direct summands correspond to the primes).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Indeed, I was thinking about the same, but you were faster!

Comment: @EricWofsey: Amusing, given the username... if $D$ is any PID (or even UFD) that has infinitely many nonassociate primes, then its field of fractions should do it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Or even just the field of fractions of *any* Noetherian domain that has infinitely many nonassociate prime elements.

Comment: It's a little weird to say "has a lot more elements". How are you counting? If $\mathbb{K}$ is infinite, then it is at least countable, and the cardinality of your two groups are clearly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z} \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}$ Actually I think the claim to be false. A counter example should be given by $\Q^*$.

The short version is to observe that $\Q^*$ is isomorphic to $\Z/2\Z \times \bigoplus_{n \in \N} \Z$, then by the following chain of isomorphisms
$$\Z/2\Z \times \bigoplus_{n \in N} \Z \cong \Z/2\Z \times \Z \times \bigoplus_{n \in N} \Z \cong \Z \times \Z/2\Z \times \bigoplus_{n \in N} \Z \cong \Z \times \Q^*$$
it follows that $\Q^* \cong \Z \times \Q^*$.

To see the isomorphism between $\Q^*$ and $\Z/2\Z \times \Z$ consider the following map
$$
\begin{align*}
f \colon \Z/2\Z \times \bigoplus_{n \in \N} \Z & \longrightarrow Q^* \\
f(s, \bar a) = (-1)^s \prod_{n \in \N} p_n^{a_n}
\end{align*}
$$
where $s \in \Z/2\Z$, $\bar a =(a_n) \in \bigoplus_n \Z$ and for each natural number $n$ the number $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number in $\N$.

By a simple calculation one can prove that $f$ is indeed a group homomorphism:
$$
\begin{align*}
f((s,\bar a)+(t,\bar b)) &= f((s+t,\bar a + \bar n)) \\
&= (-1)^{s+t} \prod_n p_n^{a_n+b_n} \\
&= (-1)^s \prod_n p_n^{a_n} (-1)^t \prod_n p_n^{b_n} \\
&= f((s,\bar a)) f((t,\bar b))
\end{align*}
$$

The injectivity follows by observing that $f((s,\bar a)) = 1$ if and only if
$(-1)^s\prod_n p_n^{a_n} = 1$, which happens only if $s=0$ and for every $n$ we have $p_n^{a_n}=1$, that is if $a_n=0$.

Surjectivity follows observing that the image of $f$ contains all the integers which generate $\Q^*$.

I hope this helps.